# Selector fails to access "Row" of v-data-table of Vuetify

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

Selector() failed to access `Row` component in v-data-table of Vuetify.

[Issue in GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors/issues/53)

Can anyone help me out to resolve this?

### Environments

- Chrome 89.0.4389.128 / macOS 11.2.3
- node: v14.15.5
- yarn: 1.22.10
- testcafe: 1.14.0
- testcafe-vue-selectors:  3.1.0
- vuetify: 2.4.2

### Test Codes tried

```js
const transfersTableRow = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data-table row');
const transfersTableRow = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data-table row').nth(0);
const transfersTableRow = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data-table Row');
const transfersTableRow = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data-table Row').nth(0);
```

[image]

### Results

```sh
 1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector([function])

      Browser: Chrome 89.0.4389.128 / macOS 11.2.3

         18 |    .typeText(amountInput, amount, { replace: true, paste: true })
         19 |    .click(transferButton)
         20 |    .click(proceedButton);
         21 |
         22 |  const transfersTableRow = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data-table row');
       > 23 |  await t.hover(transfersTableRow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the `testcafe-vue-selectors` module. You should waiting until the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors/issues/51 is fixed.